# The purpose behind lxml.htm.clean to remove 'style' from tags

Tags: python, sanitization, html-sanitizing, lxml.html

I am using lxml.html.clean to sanitize html. It seems to remove 'style' attributes from all tags and for my purposes I need the style attributes to not be removed.

Before I start allowing, I am keen to understand if there are any security implications around not removing style attributes at the time of sanitizing html.

Any insight on this matter from the gurus out there will be highly appreciated.

(please note my application allows an end user to create html which is saved on a backend database and then rendered on pages. 'clean' above works well in removing any malicious html (e.g. javascript, etc) from the html before it is saved for subsequent rendering).

Per [feedparser HTML sanitisation web site](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/html-sanitization.html) - 'style' is not present in the list of 'safe_attrs'

(Also, sorry if this is a pedestrian question. I am new to html/sanitization and related security aspects)

Comment: Looks to me like that's just [an option you can turn off](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean.Cleaner-class.html), or is that not what you're using?

Comment: Thanks Two-Bit ! It seems something that be turned off, however, I was just wondering why by default 'style' attributes are removed - is there a security issue for malicious code to make use of this attribute ? (I will enhance the question to clarify)

Comment: Maybe someone else will chime in on that. For my, er. two bits (gulp), I'd say it's likely not _security_ per se (how much can you really do with HTML attributes?) as that it's a source of a lot of needless cruft. Many, many JavaScript libraries, browser extensions, and other things can add onto this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under normal conditions, styles are not a security risk per se. However, there are several circumstances in which a malicious style could be a liability:

- `form` and `input` elements with `style="display:none"` can auto-populate with data in some browsers, causing users to unknowingly submit extra data.
- `style="display:block"` or another `display` style might break a layout expecting `inline` or another style.
- If your layout engine wants to maintain a particular visual style, allowing style information in the `style` attribute will give authors/posters more latitude than indented for choosing styles. (What if they decide they want 2000pt font?)
- Style attributes can sometimes load other styles through the `@import` mechanic, or cause URLs to be loaded via `background` and similar attributes. Unless the sanitizer commits to also sanitize the CSS code, this will be a potential vector for injection.

Since the only reason you'd want to sanatize is that the source is potentially untrusted or insecure, it's assumed that letting the source set their own styles is not desired.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. For me formatting nuances is not a problem, but the '@' mechanic is something I need to read into and understand, how to customize the cleaning of css for this, while allowing 'style' attributes. Thanks !